# Round/CEIL in SSAS calculated measure

Tags: ssas, mdx, calculated-field

I want to convert seconds into minutes according to the user.

For Example:
If user did 2 calls of 20 seconds then my caluclations are converting it to two calls of 60 sec=120s

But I want to change it to **20+20 =40s ~ 60s**

Can anyone help me with this?

I have used below MDX

```
CASE [USAGETYPE].[USAGETYPE]
WHEN [USAGETYPE].[USAGETYPE].&[VOICE] THEN (ROUND(([Measures].[RATEDVOLUME]/60))*60)
WHEN [USAGETYPE].[USAGETYPE].&[ROAMING VOICE] THEN (ROUND(([Measures].[RATEDVOLUME]/60))*60)
```

But it is converting 20 sec to 0 mins.
Can anyone tell me what is equavalant of ceil function in MDX

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a base measure, hide it and then create a calculated measure that does the rounding of the aggregated value.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want convert:
20s -> 1m;
40s -> 1m;
60s -> 1m;
80s -> 2m;
?

Then try the reverse int:

```
-int(-[Measures].[RATEDVOLUME]/60)
```